# adding a gridview's values in a label with asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview and a button.When I click the button a sentence is written in my form. I want call the datas entered in the gridview and see them in the label.
Here is my code but it does not work:

```
//code of gridview:
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            CssClass="grid">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImageUrl" HeaderText="image">
                    <ControlStyle Height="130px" Width="130px" />
                </asp:ImageField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="department" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="name" 
                    SortExpression="ProductName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="code" 
                    SortExpression="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
        </asp:GridView>
//the code of button
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             if (RadioButton2.Checked)
                txtid.Text = "name"+ProductName+"department"+description+"code"+productID;
       
    }
```

Comment: And which row out of the grid do you want this button to take data from ? Is a current row selected?

Comment: I have just one row in my gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we want to get/grab/fetch data from a given row in the grid.
And in this case, we want the first row.

For data bound fields/columns, you have to use the .cells collection of the given row. (for templated controls (say standard asp.net text boxes, you have to use find control).

So, to get that data, you can use this:
0 would be image,
1 would be Description
2 would be ProductName
3 would be productID

Hence:

```
GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[0];

txtid.Text = "name" + gvRow.Cells[2].Text
   + "department" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "code" + gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
```